# How to implement Membership provider for MVC4 Razor, with Ninject and Repository Pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, simplemembership, ninject.web.mvc

I unable to understand how to implement Membership provider with MVC4 Using DI (Ninject) and Repository pattern ?

Any body please  provide any code sample to understand how to implement this !!!

Answer (score 0):

These guys wrote just the book you are looking for and has sample code: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242361](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361)

They build up an app using Membership, Ninject, Repository Pattern and MVC4.

Comment: @ Matthew: It Is not what I am looking for. It is a bad investment for me :(

Comment: Are you sure? $30 and it is exactly what you are asking. Is is the book I used.

Comment: ya purchase the kindle version. I say a code of **MembershipRepository**, but very limited implementation, not enough. But I found this link: [http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/] very useful.

Comment: Link needs a bracket removed from the en ']', but thanks for posting back, should be useful to all.

Comment: Url: [custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection)